# How do I create a Go docker image with bazel when also needing libstdc++?

Tags: c++, docker, go, bazel

I am trying to create a docker image out of a mostly-go source base. The problem is that the go code also calls a C++ library (libsodium), so the generated container lacks libstdc++.

Here is my approach: first, I bundle the distroless go image with a few things created with `pkg_tar()`:

```
container_image(
    name = "new_base_image",
    base = "@go_image_base//image",
    tars = [
      ":bash_static_tar",
      ":passwd_tar",
      ":dirs_tar",
    ],
    visibility = ["//:__subpackages__"],
)
```

Then I create my go image, package it, and push it to my registry:

```
go_image(
    name = "alice-go-image",
    embed = [":alice_lib"],
    base = "//:new_base_image",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)


container_image(
    name = "alice-image",
    base = ":alice-go-image",
    user = "alice",
    entrypoint = "/bin/sh",
    directory = "/opt/alice",
    workdir = "/opt/alice",
)

container_push(
    name = "alice-push",
    format = "Docker",
    image = ":alice-image",
    registry = "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev",
    repository = "mycoolproject/pub-docker/alice",
)
```

Unforunately, the Go code calls some vendored C++ code (libsodium, not that it matters), so attempting to run the resulting binary from within the container yields:

```
sh-5.1$ ./apollo                                                                                                                                                                        
./alice: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I *thought* I could simply include the distroless CC image in a bundle, but I cannot figure out how to do it. I would think that putting

```
container_load(
    name = "distroless-cc",
    registry = "gcr.io",
    repository = "distroless/cc",
    tag = "latest",
)
```

in the `WORKSPACE`, then including the `@distroless-cc//image` label as one of the entries in the `tars` attribute of `container_image` would do the trick. Unfortunately, what it does instead is include the `layer.tar` files and associated metadata as part of the image! That is, if I change the first rule to:

```
container_image(
    name = "new_base_image",
    base = "@go_image_base//image",
    tars = [
      ":bash_static_tar",
      ":passwd_tar",
      ":dirs_tar",
      "@distroless-cc//image",
    ],
    visibility = ["//:__subpackages__"],
)
```

the result is:

```
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 1969-12-31 19:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 1969-12-31 19:00 ./bin/
-r-xr-xr-x 0/0         1248656 1969-12-31 19:00 ./bin/sh
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 1969-12-31 19:00 ./etc/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0              74 1969-12-31 19:00 ./etc/passwd
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 1969-12-31 19:00 ./opt/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 1969-12-31 19:00 ./opt/config/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             776 1969-12-31 19:00 ./46bdf18e6b66057ca3b88eb8e0e2b8443297e36629e5fba3f33c2b2c717aa083.json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0         3061760 1969-12-31 19:00 ./4441c0604495fd6824901b4a57c65ffbb9025023edc1bee6f1a8fe2c312347a3/layer.tar
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             245 1969-12-31 19:00 ./4441c0604495fd6824901b4a57c65ffbb9025023edc1bee6f1a8fe2c312347a3/json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               3 1969-12-31 19:00 ./4441c0604495fd6824901b4a57c65ffbb9025023edc1bee6f1a8fe2c312347a3/VERSION
-rw-r--r-- 0/0        17786880 1969-12-31 19:00 ./51aee51224937d5c4fe6e805be3dac78ace093d894d99923afb39a6fbcb9711b/layer.tar
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             321 1969-12-31 19:00 ./51aee51224937d5c4fe6e805be3dac78ace093d894d99923afb39a6fbcb9711b/json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               3 1969-12-31 19:00 ./51aee51224937d5c4fe6e805be3dac78ace093d894d99923afb39a6fbcb9711b/VERSION
-rw-r--r-- 0/0         1996800 1969-12-31 19:00 ./605a66edf924fdfdddccc79e556050288e91ecf53a2d71fa8c17d793c7d26451/layer.tar
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             485 1969-12-31 19:00 ./605a66edf924fdfdddccc79e556050288e91ecf53a2d71fa8c17d793c7d26451/json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               3 1969-12-31 19:00 ./605a66edf924fdfdddccc79e556050288e91ecf53a2d71fa8c17d793c7d26451/VERSION
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             359 1969-12-31 19:00 ./manifest.json
-rw-r--r-- 0/0              92 1969-12-31 19:00 ./repositories
```

Which is clearly not what I want!

Of course I could manually create an image by untarring the go and the cc distroless images together and then pushing it to my private registry, but that would require doing stuff manually, and I can't figure out how to do it with the bazel docker rules.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to assure that all of the dependancies for your code are installed in the image in order to be able to use the resulting image (without additional installation). This means that you need to install the libraries and binaries (in your case `libstdc++` and other dependent libraries).
Unfortunately, `bazel` rules do not run the `Docker` container, rather, they are assembling static files (layers) in a resulting image, so you will not be able to install them during the packaging.

One approach would be to create a `base image` with all tools and libraries you need and use this image as a starting point for the `basel`. This can be done with the standard `docker` build tools by creating a `Dockerfile` that prepares the environment and pushing the resulting file to the repository (or as a `tar` file) to be used as a base for `basel`

Another approach is to create the dependancies as a `tar` layers and use them to assemble the image with `container_layer("tars"=[])` and add the layer to the `container_image("layers"=)`, however this is not recommended due to two major issues: 1) Creating the `tar` is complex and prone to errors, and, 2) the `tar` is static, so the subsequent builds will not include the patches and minor updates.

Comment: Using `distroless-cc` as the *base* image was actually the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

As @JayEye later self answered in @jordanvrtanoski's answer, using `@distroless-cc` as base image should fix this problem.

To give more color on this, we first need to understand "distroless" images and how they are used by the various `<language>_image` rules from [rules_docker](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker).

**Distroless Container Images**

From [GoogleContainerTools github page](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless),

> "Distroless" images contain only your application and its runtime dependencies. They do not contain package managers, shells or any other programs you would expect to find in a standard Linux distribution.

They further list the various images available. Some examples include - gcr.io/distroless/[static-debian11 | base-debian11 | cc-debian11 | python3-debian11 | ...]

**<language>_image rules**

Now coming to the `go_image` rule, if you set the `pure` attribute of the rule to "on" then the static-debian11 image is used. If `pure` attribute is not set or set to "off" then the base-debian11 distroless image is used.

To see what each of these distroless container images contain, you can look at the distroless github page.

For example, the difference between base and static is specified [here](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/main/base/README.md)

```
This [static] image contains a minimal Linux, glibc-based system.
It is intended for use directly by "mostly-statically compiled"
languages like Go, Rust or D.

Statically compiled applications (Go) that do not require
libc can use the gcr.io/distroless/static image, which contains:

- ca-certificates
- A /etc/passwd entry for a root user
- A /tmp directory
- tzdata

Most other applications (and Go apps that require libc/cgo) 
should start with gcr.io/distroless/base, which contains 
all of the packages in gcr.io/distroless/static, and

- glibc
- libssl
- openssl
```

Lastly, the reason distroless-cc work is because it contains libgcc1 (and its dependencies) bundled into the image along with everything in the base image.

From [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/main/cc/README.md)

> the image contains everything in the base image, plus: libgcc1 and its dependencies